# epoch difference in Makefiles

Tags: bash, makefile, epoch, gnu-make

Below is a part of my Makefile (has errors). I just want the difference between the epoch and the epoch max and print them. But I am not sure what the mistake is. Could someone help me with this.
Thanks

```
EPOCH_MAX = 1400000000

identifier:
    epoch = $(shell date +%s)
    echo $(epoch)
    residue = $(epoch)-$(EPOCH_MAX) 
    echo $(residue)
```

I get the following error

```
epoch = 1400767572
make: epoch: Command not found
make: *** [identifier] Error 127
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up Makefile variables and shell variables.
The following code is what you probably want:

```
  EPOCH_MAX = 1400000000
  epoch = $(shell date +%s )

  identifier:
        echo $(epoch)
        (( residue = $(epoch) - $(EPOCH_MAX) )) || true ;\
        echo $${residue}
```

**EDIT:** As MadScientist stressed, this isn't portable at all. Better is e.g.:

```
  EPOCH_MAX = 1400000000

  identifier:
      epoch=$(shell date +%s ); \
      echo $$epoch; \
      residue=`expr $$epoch - $(EPOCH_MAX)`; \
      echo $$residue
```

Comment: Don't use bash constructs in make recipes.  It's not portable.  Use POSIX shell constructs only.

Comment: Also you don't need the `|| true` here, because `echo` is the last command and its exit code is 0; you don't care what the exit code of the assignment is.

Comment: Thank you, I am new to Makefiles. But still "residue" value is not printed. It says /bin/sh: 1: residue: not found

Comment: @user2532296: Do you have by any chance a space at the end of line 6? The line *must* end with backslash.

Comment: I don't have any space. I get the following error.                          echo 1400770606
1400770606
((residue = 1400770606 - 1400000000 ));\
        echo ${residue}
/bin/sh: 1: residue: not found

Comment: Is your shell a bash? If not, it might not work since it is (as MadScientist stessed) a non-portable approach.

Comment: yes my shell is bash. so what is the posix equivalent ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54221/discussion-between-user2532296-and-matthias).

Answer (score 1):

The following also seems to work fine. But uses the shell.

```
EPOCH_MAX = 1400000000
epoch = $(shell date +%s )
residue =$(shell echo $(epoch)\-$(EPOCH_MAX) | bc)


identifier:
   echo $(epoch)
   echo $(residue)
```